# Start UITableView at place other than beginning of array iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsmutablearray

if indexOfObject called on an NSMUtableArray returns the place in that array of that object, how you do start a UITableView at that Integer rather than at the beginning of the array?

Ex. If I Have an array of 200 objects, and indexOfObject returns 52, how do I start the list of 200 at 52 instead of 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to make use of:

`- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated`

of `UITableView`.

So, in your case:

```
NSIndexPath *offsetIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:52];
self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:offsetIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPostionTop animated:YES];
```

`UITableViewScrollPositionTop` tells the table view to place this row at the top of the screen.

You can obviously decide if you want to animate this transition or not.